# If there are no orders on the current month, there will be no row for that month

Tags: sql-server

I'm training in SQL Server and got this task:

> show sales volume for each employee for the 1997 year month by month. Result should contain 108 records (9*12). Only one query

I'm using the Northwind sample database.

My query:

```
Select      
     dbo.Employees.EmployeeID
    , dbo.Employees.FirstName
    , dbo.Employees.LastName
    , MONTH(OrderDate) as [Month]
    --, YEAR(OrderDate) as [Year]
    , sum([Order Details].Quantity*[Order Details].UnitPrice) as [Sales Volume]
from 
   Orders
Inner join 
   dbo.[Order Details] on dbo.[Order Details].OrderID = dbo.Orders.OrderID
Inner join 
   dbo.Employees on dbo.Employees.EmployeeID = dbo.Orders.EmployeeID
where 
   DATEPART(year, OrderDate) = 1997
group by 
   Month(OrderDate), 
   dbo.Employees.EmployeeID, dbo.Employees.FirstName, 
   dbo.Employees.LastName
order by 
   dbo.Employees.EmployeeID;
```

Unfortunately, I got only 104 records, because they are some months, when employees didn't have any orders (I want to set it to 0, for example) for this rows).

I know, that I need a calendar table or special sub-query. But I can't resolve it (about 2 days).

I find something like this, but I can't add this code block to my solution.

```
Select 
   DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '1997-01-01'), 0)) StartDate,
   DATEADD(MONTH, n+1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '1997-01-01'), 0)) EndDate
FROM 
   (SELECT TOP 12
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID) - 1) as n
    FROM Orders) as n
```

May someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have the query, SQL Server 2008 or above is required:

```
WITH Months AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) AS M(MonthNumber)
)
, EmployeesMonths AS
(
    SELECT
        E.EmployeeID, E.FirstName, E.LastName, Months.MonthNumber
    FROM
        dbo.Employees E
        CROSS JOIN Months
)
, SalesSummary AS
(
    SELECT
        O.EmployeeID,
        MONTH(O.OrderDate) AS MonthNumber,
        SUM(OD.UnitPrice * OD.Quantity * (1 - OD.Discount)) AS Sales
    FROM
        dbo.Orders O
        INNER JOIN dbo.[Order Details] OD
            ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
    WHERE
        YEAR(O.OrderDate) = 1997
    GROUP BY
        O.EmployeeID, MONTH(O.OrderDate)

)
SELECT
    EM.EmployeeID, EM.FirstName, EM.LastName, EM.MonthNumber,
    CAST(ISNULL(SS.Sales, 0) AS decimal(18,2)) AS Sales
FROM
    EmployeesMonths EM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesSummary SS
        ON EM.EmployeeID = SS.EmployeeID AND EM.MonthNumber = SS.MonthNumber
ORDER BY
    EM.EmployeeID, EM.MonthNumber
```

EDIT:
The above query uses chained CTE's (Common Table Expresions). Chained CTE's allows you to approach your problem step by step, you don't need to think on the whole thing at once. First we need months, then we need a cartesian product of Employees and months. A sales summary by month and employee is also needed. Finally we glue all things together on the last query.

Comment: We have a problem just with OD tables in this query)) I'll try to fix it. I'll write you about it. Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm sorry I hate white spaces in table names, so I always rename [Order Details] table to OrderDetails, removing white spaces. I edited my answer replacing the name the other way around

Comment: Of course, I found this space before read your comments about it. Thanks a lot. For me, it's not trivial query) And now I'll try to find another ways to solve this task.

Comment: It isn't a trivial query indeed. What other ways are you thinking on? You can use Virtual Auxiliary Table of Numbers ( http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers ) instead of Table Value Constructor ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx ) for months. You can use derived tables instead of chained CTE's too.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

```
DECLARE @o TABLE
    (
      orderid INT ,
      empid INT ,
      orderdate DATETIME ,
      amount MONEY
    )
DECLARE @e TABLE
    (
      empid INT ,
      name NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )


INSERT  INTO @e
VALUES  ( 1, 'Bob' ),
        ( 2, 'Peter' ),
        ( 3, 'Charley' )
INSERT  INTO @o
VALUES  ( 1, 1, '20140101', 100 ),
        ( 1, 1, '20150101', 1 ),
        ( 2, 1, '20150102', 2 ),
        ( 3, 1, '20150201', 2.5 ),
        ( 4, 2, '20150101', 4 ),
        ( 5, 2, '20150103', 20 ),
        ( 6, 2, '20150104', 1 )


SELECT  m.id ,
        e.empid ,
        e.name ,
        ISNULL(SUM(o.amount), 0) AS summ
FROM    ( VALUES ( 1), ( 2), ( 3), ( 4), ( 5), ( 6), ( 7), ( 8), ( 9), ( 10),
        ( 11), ( 12) ) AS m ( id )
        CROSS JOIN @e e 
        LEFT JOIN @o o ON m.id = MONTH(o.orderdate) AND e.empid = o.empid
WHERE DATEPART(year, OrderDate) = 2015 OR o.orderid IS NULL
GROUP BY m.id ,
        e.empid ,
        e.name
        ORDER BY e.empid, m.id
```

Output:

```
id  empid   name    summ
1   1       Bob     3.00
2   1       Bob     2.50
3   1       Bob     0.00
4   1       Bob     0.00
5   1       Bob     0.00
6   1       Bob     0.00
7   1       Bob     0.00
8   1       Bob     0.00
9   1       Bob     0.00
10  1       Bob     0.00
11  1       Bob     0.00
12  1       Bob     0.00
1   2       Peter   25.00
2   2       Peter   0.00
3   2       Peter   0.00
4   2       Peter   0.00
5   2       Peter   0.00
6   2       Peter   0.00
7   2       Peter   0.00
8   2       Peter   0.00
9   2       Peter   0.00
10  2       Peter   0.00
11  2       Peter   0.00
12  2       Peter   0.00
1   3       Charley 0.00
2   3       Charley 0.00
3   3       Charley 0.00
4   3       Charley 0.00
5   3       Charley 0.00
6   3       Charley 0.00
7   3       Charley 0.00
8   3       Charley 0.00
9   3       Charley 0.00
10  3       Charley 0.00
11  3       Charley 0.00
12  3       Charley 0.00
```

Comment: Just one query is the requirement, you have more than one.

Comment: Where did you see more then 1 query??

Comment: On the question:  "show sales volume for each employee for the 1997 year month by month. Result should contain 108 records (9*12). Only one query".

Comment: Insert - it is a query too

Comment: There is JUST 1 query man. Can you show me the second one :) OP has just to adjust his schema upon my answer.
INSERTs HERE ARE JUST FOR DEMONSTRATION.

Comment: inserts counts as queries too. Technically it's not a query, its a sql statement. But I'm sure the OP's teacher would not like your anwser. I'm sure he/she means  just one sql statement. And of course no schema changes are allowed. Because schema changes entails more sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select      
     dbo.Employees.EmployeeID
    , dbo.Employees.FirstName
    , dbo.Employees.LastName
    , [Month].[Month]
    --, YEAR(OrderDate) as [Year]
    , sum([Order Details].Quantity*[Order Details].UnitPrice) as [Sales Volume]
from dbo.Employees
CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT 1 [month]
    UNION   SELECT 2
    UNION   SELECT 3
    UNION   SELECT 4
    UNION   SELECT 5
    UNION   SELECT 6
    UNION   SELECT 7
    UNION   SELECT 8
    UNION   SELECT 9
    UNION   SELECT 10
    UNION   SELECT 11
    UNION   SELECT 12
) [month]
LEFT JOIN Orders on dbo.Employees.EmployeeID = dbo.Orders.EmployeeID AND [month].[month]=Month(OrderDate)
LEFT join dbo.[Order Details] on dbo.[Order Details].OrderID = dbo.Orders.OrderID
where DATEPART(year, OrderDate) = 1997
group by [Month].[Month], dbo.Employees.EmployeeID, dbo.Employees.FirstName, dbo.Employees.LastName
order by dbo.Employees.EmployeeID;
```